# Field "FILE" Data is always empty?

Tags: javascript, alpacajs

I'm trying to use for the first time the field "FILE", and what I wanted is to see is the file URI or the data/image in base64 format but after I clicked on submit I've got nothing !

I'm I using that field incorrectly?

```
$("#field1").alpaca({
    "data": "",
    "options": {
        "type": "file",
             "label": "Ice Cream Photo:",
             "helper": "Pick your favorite ice cream picture.",
        "form": {
        "attributes": {
            "action": "http://httpbin.org/post",
                "method": "post"
        },
            "buttons": {
            "submit": {
                "click": function () {
                    $('#data').html(JSON.stringify(this.topControl.data));
                    this.refreshValidationState(true);
                    if (!this.isValid(true)) {
                        this.focus();
                        return;
                    }
                    this.ajaxSubmit();
                }
            }
        }
    },
},
    "schema": {
        "type": "string",
           "format": "uri"
     }
});
```

here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vert3x/k1a3w0fh/1/

Thank you.

Comment: with ajaxSubmit(), console.log or showing the data in a dom I got nothing!! I got the data in base64 format only if I use the selectionHandler event.

`"selectionHandler": function(files, data) {
       console.log(data);
}`

Comment: \*shrugs\* then use `selectionHandler`, what's the problem with it?

Comment: "You won't be getting much answers for that, because nobody knows how to work with it." thanks for the motivation man :) I'm not asking only you to help "you don't know how to work with it." so please go find another question and stop posting this kind of comments.